# Getting Facebook wall post to my webpage

Tags: asp.net, facebook-graph-api, c#-4.0

Is there any Facebook API for getting Facebook post to get immediately into web application using ASP.NET

using **string url = string.Format("https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id={0}&redirect_uri={1}&scope={2}&code={3}&client_secret={4}", app_id, Request.Url.AbsoluteUri, scope, Request["code"].ToString(), app_secret);**  I can get Access_Token.

Using Access_Token I can get All Posted Files  into my web application.

But I have a requirement like show files Immediately once they post in Facebook.

Is it possible? if possible which API is available to get like immediate post?

Answer (score 0):

I have used [Facebook SDK for .NET](http://facebooksdk.net/docs/web/) and happy with it so far. Check the link and see if it works for you too. The API is well documented and they have sample applications and tutorial right there.